# Does dotenv-webpack expose all environment variables from .env to front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, environment-variables

I am building an application that has public keys for some APIs and private keys for other APIs. I would like to store all of them inside of my single `.env` file and use `dotenv` to provide the private keys to my server and `dotenv-webpack` to provide the public keys to my public front-end javascript. Will using this package make my private keys available in my javascript or will it only take the ones it needs?

Example:

```
# .env file
public_key="12345"
private_key="45678"
```

This one needs to be accessed on the fron end

```
// javascript file on front end
var publicKey = process.env.public_key
```

But I would like to keep this one hidden

```
// javascript file in node.js
var privateKey = process.env.private_key
```

The package I am considering using is this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The github page of the [plugin](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) states that:

> dotenv-webpack wraps dotenv and Webpack.DefinePlugin. As such, it overwrites existing any existing DefinePlugin configurations. Also, like DefinePlugin, it does a text replace in the resulting bundle for any instances of process.env.
>
> Your .env files can include sensitive information. Because of this,dotenv-webpack will only include defined environment variables in the final bundle.

So its safe. It will only expose the environment variables which you actually use in the code.