# Configure ES6 Application to read configurations from .env file

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, environment-variables

Following the :https://12factor.net/config
I'm trying to configure my Angular5 app to read the settings from the `.env` file.

---

I have an .env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

I'm trying to import it on one of my `.ts` file

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
const myEnv = dotenv.config();
console.log(myEnv);
```

I kept getting this in my Chrome console

> {error: TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function at Object.config (http://localhost:4300/vendor.bund…}

How can I resolve this error?

I just want to be able to access my settings from my .env file.

---

> That is not answer what I am looking for.

- The link to the answer only shows how to import it via webpack. I used npm.
- The answers on that link show the answer on ES5. I used ES6.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to expose your configuration file (containing passwords) on the Internet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does dotenv-webpack expose all environment variables from .env to front end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656354/does-dotenv-webpack-expose-all-environment-variables-from-env-to-front-end)

Comment: @str : the link to the answer only show how to import it via webpack. I used npm.

Comment: @str : the answer on that link show the answer on ES5. I used ES6.

Comment: ES5 and ES6 is not a contraction. Neither is npm and webpack. You need a module bundler anyway to make that code available on current browsers.

Comment: What is module bundler ? The code in teh link you shared is not telling me that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158998/discussion-between-ihue-and-str).

Comment: In order for a .ts file to become readable in a browser, you need something like webpack or grunt to bundle it into a vanilla JS module.  That's referred to as a 'module bundler'.